# Is there any way to remove the varchar single cuotes in a has_many relationship query in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a preexisting database where the primary_key of a table is integer and it is used as a foreign_key in another table but as a string.
I want the query:

```
SELECT * FROM crcec WHERE crcecoper = 12183
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM crcec WHERE crcecoper = '12183'
```

Without the quotes, the query works perfectly, but doing:

```
ifx_credit = IfxCredit.find(12183)
ifx_credit.ifx_previsions
```

It puts the single quotes on the id.

Models:

```
class IfxCredit < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :informix
    self.pluralize_table_names = false
    self.table_name = "prmpr "
    self.primary_key = "prmprnpre"

    has_many :ifx_previsions, -> { order "crcecfech" }, class_name: "IfxPrevision", foreign_key: "crcecoper"
end

class IfxPrevision < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :informix
    self.pluralize_table_names = false
    self.table_name = "crcec "
    self.primary_key = "crcecoper"

    belongs_to :ifx_credit, class_name: "IfxCredit", foreign_key: "crcecoper"
 end
```

The primary_key is "prmprnpre" and the foreign_key is "crcecoper". Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

"crcec" has, for example, the following data in the "crcecoper" field:

```
"0000012133"
"0000012143"
"0000012163"
"0000012173"
"0000012183"
```

"prmpr" has the following data in the "prmprnpre" field:

```
12133
12143
12163
12173
12183
```

For this reason, the query doesn't work with quotes.

Comment: so, the foreign key column is of type string?

Comment: Yes, or varchar

Comment: So why do you want the query to use integer? Also, doesn't query with a string produce correct result anyway?

Comment: The table "crcec" has, for example, a record with crcecoper = "0000012133" and that is the foreign_key of the primary_key prmprnpre = 12133. So, when the query is "SELECT * FROM crcec WHERE crcecoper = '12133'" the result is empty, instead, when the query is "SELECT * FROM crcec WHERE crcecoper = 12133" the result is the record that I want.

Comment: I see. I suppose, converting one of the columns to the same data type is off the table?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, Sergio. I can't modify the columns, only use them. It is a very old database.